# Finding a basis of Im(T).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T(a,b,c,d) = ad * x + c + d.

How would I go about finding the basis of the kernel of T?

I know that ad = c = d = 0 to satisfy the condition, but I'm having difficulty putting ad = 0 into matrices to form a basis. We can have (1,0,0,0) or (0,0,0,1), and the condition is satisfied, but it is strictly or, as if a=1 and d=2, the condition is not satisfied (a*d=2=!0). How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instante, the function $\textsf{T}(a,b,c,d)=(ad)x+(c+d)$
is not a linear transformation. To see why, consider $\textsf{T}(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c,\lambda d)=(\lambda^2ad)+\lambda(c+d)$ but $\lambda \textsf{T}(a,b,c,d)=\lambda(ad)x+\lambda(c+d)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought about checking the linearity first...